# Why does layout of HTML page change when adding text

Tags: html, css, wordpress

if you look at [my test site](http://js1.biz) you will see a WordPress site.  On the home page, there is a "Toolbox" section with 9 posts.  I would expect the layout to be 3 x 3, but it shows up as 3/1/3/2 and there is no apparent reason.

If I change one line of html to a test string, then they do show up as 3 x 3.  The line is showing the post excerpt and there is no extra formatting going on that I can see.

From looking at the HTML, the two different pages are identical.  The both have a single

```
<p>some text here</p>
```

I have tried short test data, long test data ect, and it all looks fine.  It's just when I use "get_the_excerpt();" that the layout is then thrown off.

I have tried using F12 dev tools, but I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: Try using a div for each row. So three rows each containing three posts each.

Comment: A div for each row would definitely help (and likely, solve)... however, it shouldn't be required. I didn't see anything obvious in the console. Odd.

Comment: The issue is that the first of your floated elements has two lines of text underneath the image, and is therefor higher as the following two. And _since_ your are using float, the next element on the next row floats underneath the second one, because there’s the first space to float into available, whereas to float underneath the first one it would have to “go further down”.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, I couldn't figure that one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In css for .blog-post you need to set a height. that is because you have the float property active and they have different heights, therefore it puts them where they would fit.

I looked on your code and I believe a height of 200px would be enough. But you change it as you need it.
Here you go:

```
.blog-post {
    float: left;
    width: 274px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0px 69px 60px 0px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Also there are other solutions to this. Like put every 3 of them in a div, or making a table with them with 3 on a row with width 100% and the text-align property set to center.